# Filtering rows in DataFrame with a numeric value OR NaN in column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove all rows with a numeric value of less than 15 in a column, but I want to retain those rows if the value is NaN. How do I this?

This line removes all rows with values less than 15, but it **also** removes all NaN rows:

```
df2 = df[(df['columnA'] >= 15)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [pandas.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = df[(df['columnA'] >= 15) | pd.isnull(df['columnA'])]
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```py
df[(df['columnA'] >=15) | (df['columnA'].isnull())]
```

But you should [better use `loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) instead of just the condition:

```py
df.loc[(df['columnA'] >=15) | (df['columnA'].isnull()), :]
```

**Warning**: don't forget the inner parenthesis, it won't work without.

[`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) detects missing values (`NaN`, `None` or `NaT`).